# An array outputting zeros instead of numbers

Tags: java, arrays

The code is supposed to output sorted array, yet it outputs zeros.

As an example, when running the program, write "2" when it asks for method, then "5", when it asks for count and "10" "9" "2" "5" "0", when it's asking for items. Then you'll see. I followed all the instructions given and I can't seem to find the problem with code, which changes inputted numbers to zeros, when outputting...

```
    public static void secondMethod(int[] a) {

        long t1 = System.nanoTime();

        int N = a.length;
        int b[] = new int[N];
        int c[] = new int[N];

        int[] tmp;
        int len = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = b[i];
        }

        while (len < N) {
            int n = 0;
            int i;
            int j;
            int ri;
            int rj;

            for (int k=0; k<b.length; k+=2*len){{
                n=k;
                i = k;
                j = k+len;

                if(k+len<N){
                    ri = k+len;
                }else{
                    ri = N;
                }
                if(k+2*len<N){
                    rj = k+2*len;
                }else{
                    rj = N;
                }
            }

            while(i<ri && j<rj){
                if(b[i]<b[j]){
                    c[n]=b[i];
                    i++;
                    n++;
                }else{
                    c[n]=b[j];
                    j++;
                    n++;
                }
            }
            while(i<ri){
                c[n]=b[i];
                i++;
                n++;
            }
            while(j<rj){
                c[n]=b[j];
                j++;
                n++;
            }
            }
            len = len*2;

            tmp = b;
            b = c;
            c = tmp;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = b[i];
        }

        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        long t = t2 - t1;
        System.out.println("t=" + t);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int nm, mtd;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("method: ");
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            mtd = sc.nextInt();
        else {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            sc.close();
            return;
        }
        if (mtd != 1 && mtd != 2) {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            sc.close();
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("count: ");
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            nm = sc.nextInt();
        else {
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            sc.close();
            return;
        }

        int a[] = new int[nm];

        System.out.println("items: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            if (sc.hasNextInt())
                a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            else {
                System.out.println("input-output error");
                sc.close();
                return;
            }

        }
        sc.close();
        if (mtd == 1) {
            firstMethod(a);
            System.out.println("sorted: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
        if (mtd == 2){
            secondMethod(a);
            System.out.println("sorted: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, in the `secondMethod(int[] a)` method, in the first for loop, use

```
b[i] = a[i];
```

instead of

```
a[i] = b[i];
```

and it should work.
Try debugging next time, it helps.

Comment: "Try debugging next time, it helps.".  90% of SO questions could be easily solved with this advice.

Comment: I didn't know what debugging even is, I'll be checking out this though https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/tutorial-debugging-your-first-java-application.html that the guy above gave.

Comment: If it works, accept this answer as shown here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Debugging allows you to execute your code "step-by-step". With most modern day IDEs like Eclipse, Intellij, etc. you can also see what the values of variables are, evaluate expressions, etc. You should learn how to do it, and life will be much simpler if you get how to do it properly.

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD I did, thank you a lot, such a silly mistake... I'll definitely learn it!